# Framework selection stay or switch?

Tags: professionalism

I am not sure that my question fit to the `workplace` or not, but I known no where to ask. I am confusing since this is my first time in big transitioning non-tech to partial-tech company. And I am placed in the tech-lead position.

I have full authority of select the tech stack since I myself can be able to finish `system, backend, CI/CD, ML, frontend, and talk to customer`. However, the company has former teammates. They use different tools from me.
I use `React` because of the followings

**Background:**
1. Backed by big company
2. Opensource
3. `ES6`
4. I know boiler plate which has ready made TDD with `ReduxReducer`
5. I don't know `VueJS, nor Angular`

**Hesitations:**
One thing I am concern right now is re-using the former project component written in `VueJS`. I heard that on top most of the code you can refactor `React` to use interchangeably share with any `Component` no matter it is written from other framework.

**In the mean time:**
1. Practicing `VueJS`. To figure out `pro` and `con` and how to reuse it with `React` or even follow the team decision. Since existing member can give me a comment

**Questions:**
1. Should I stay using `ReactJS` or switch to `VueJS`?
2. What is the outcome of the first question?
3. Am I doing the best decision?

Comment: While they have both pros and cons...do not forget to check if the other team members know React or not. To be a teach lead is not only about yourself.  Think how much resources you're wasting if other 5 people need to learn it, company might have better usages for that money.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One thing I am concern right now is re-using the former project component written in VueJS. I heard that on top most of the code you can refactor React to use interchangeably share with any Component no matter it is written from other framework.

Start with a proper research to understand your limitations. If it turns out you're limited to VueJS because of that component - you got your answer. If it's not a limitation - pick whatever technology you and your team are most comfortable with.

And, for as much as possible, do not marry your codebase to one single framework. Make sure your core business logic depends on abstractions and not implementation details. Design your system in such a way that you can replace the framework at a low cost.

Comment: `Start with a proper research to understand your limitations.` Thank you very much Egor.